# json data have square brackets how can logstash interpret it?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm going to receive json data from logstash and send it to elastixsearch.

```
{
    "field_1":"TEST",
    "field_2":1005,
    "field_3":"ABCD",
    "data":[[1,2,2020023436,"test01",0,0,0,0,0], [1,2,2020023437,"test02",0,0,0,0,0]]
}
```

In ths json data format, I can read data "%{field_1}" this way.

However, in the case of data overlaid with brackets, I don't know how to interpret it in logstash

I want read "data" read by index
[0] : [1,2,2020023436,"test01",0,0,0,0,0]
[1] : [1,2,2020023437,"test02",0,0,0,0,0]

and into [0][0] : 1, [0][3] : "test01" like this way.

In this case, what filter should I use to interpret it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this but you can have a look at the '[split](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html)' filter plugin that comes with Logstash